# Combinations in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe where each row has a particular activity of a user:

```
UserID  Date    Purchased
A       1 feb   Laptop
B       2 Feb   Laptop
A       2 Feb   Car
B       2 Feb   House
```

Now I want to find the number of unique users who have purchased 2 different products (not more than 2) and their products should be 'Laptop' and 'Car'. So User A would be fall into this category. I have figured out how to get product count against each user but cant figure out how to filter user A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
df.sort_values('Purchased')\
  .groupby(['UserID'])['Purchased']\
  .agg(['first','last','nunique'])\
  .query('first=="Car" and last=="Laptop" and nunique==2')\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  UserID first    last  nunique
0      A   Car  Laptop        2
```

Comment: Novel solution!

Comment: thank you! exactly what i was looking for. Would be great if you can guide a bit more. How do i now take nunique of UserID column from the output table? And is it possible to do .isin for these userIDs in the output with another dataframe?

Comment: Yes, set statement to df_out and then use `df_out['UserID'].nunique()`  Yes, but it would be better if you asked a new question with all the data for the `isin` part.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to set the index to the "UserID", then we'll select just the users for which the condition returns True.

```
idf = df.set_index('UserID') 
idf.loc[df.groupby(['UserID'])['Purchased'].apply(lambda x: 
                                                  sorted(x)==['Car', 'Laptop'])]
```

Result:

```
In [95]: idf.loc[df.groupby(['UserID'])['Purchased'].apply(lambda x: sorted(x)==['Car', 'Laptop'])] 
Out[95]: 
              Date Purchased
UserID                      
A       2020-02-01    Laptop
A       2020-02-01       Car
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is in a database, I suggest that you could use SQL query first and process the result of SQL in python.

If the data is very large, this way is much easier and faster.

like this:

```
select UserID, count(distinct Purchased) as cnt
from table
where Purchased in ('Laptop', 'Car')
having cnt <2
```

Comment: I have the dataframe loaded. Anyway to do this in pandas?

Comment: I saw that you have 1m users in this Dataframe. Sure you can process data using pandas, but processing data in the DB would decrease the data volume in the DB side then reduce the data transfer time between DB and your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby([‘UserID’])[‘Purchased’]).nunique()
```

Comment: The dataframe has data for around 1m users. Also, this does not give combinations